# autoboxing in generic, can autoboxing work with object

Tags: java, generics, autoboxing

why no autoboxing in line sum +=nums[i].doubleValue(). u can see nums[i] is in object form why can't just write sum +=nums[i], why need doubleValue() which is manual way of autoboxing and unboxing. i have successfully compiled a program where number in form of object is returned from the method and automatically assigned as double.

```
public class genericbound<T extends Number> {
    T[] nums;
    genericbound(T[] o){
          nums=o;
    }
    double average(){
        double sum=0.0;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
            sum +=nums[i].doubleValue();
        return sum/nums.length;
    }
}
    class BoundsDemo{
public static void main(String args[]){
Integer inums[]={1,2,3,4,5};
genericbound<Integer> iob= new genericbound<Integer>(inums);
double v=iob.average();
System.out.println("iob average is"+v);
Double dnums[]={1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5 };
genericbound<Double> dob= new genericbound<Double>(dnums);
double w= dob.average();
System.out.println("dob average is "+w);
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autoboxing/Unboxing works with [Wrapper classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Like `Double, Integer, Character`.

`Number` is not a wrapper class, so it won't work with `Number`.

Your method can be modified as below to work with Integers and Doubles both.

```
double average() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        if( nums[i] instanceof Double) {                    
            sum += nums[i].doubleValue();
        } else if(nums[i] instanceof Integer) {
            sum += nums[i].intValue();
        }
    return sum / nums.length;
}
```

Comment: thanks but , i have removed the "extend Number" int the program and tried compiling but still error. where as other similar type of program is there 
    aa
    aa

Comment: thanks but , i have removed the "extend Number" int the program and tried compiling but still error. where as other similar type of program, see this line int v=iob.getob(); this program works






class Gen<T>
T ob;
Gen(T o){
ob=o;
}
T getob(){
return ob;
}
class GenDemo{
public static void main(String args[]){
Gen<Integer> iob=new Gen<Integer>(88);
int v= iob.getob();
System.out.println("value "+ v);
 }
}